Can I declare a requirement-parameter as an r-value?
I've got a thread-queue with a generic callback that takes the queue elements. This is the minimally reduced code:
template<typename Entity, typename Consumer>
    requires requires( Consumer consumer, Entity entity ) { { consumer( std::move( entity ) ) }; }
void withCallback( Consumer consumer )
{
    // ...
}

Can I also declare the parameter entity to be a r-value-reference directly like this:
template<typename Entity, typename Consumer>
    requires requires( Consumer consumer, Entity &&entity ) { { consumer( entity ) }; }
void withCallback( Consumer consumer )
{
    // ...
}


entity is lvalue in the both cases.


Can I also declare the parameter entity to be a r-value-reference directly

Yes of course (although it's "rvalue reference", not "r-value-reference").
The issue though is the same as in all code: an rvalue reference parameter is still an lvalue unless you move/forward it. So this:
requires ( Consumer consumer, Entity&& entity ) { consumer( entity ); }

means the same thing as:
requires ( Consumer consumer, Entity entity ) { consumer( entity ); }

If you want to make sure you're passing through an rvalue, you'll need to either explicitly move it:
requires ( Consumer consumer, Entity entity ) {
    consumer( std::move(entity) );
}

Or procure an rvalue in some other way, the easiest being to take a function pointer (though you'll have to remember to actually invoke the function pointer!):
requires ( Consumer consumer, Entity&& (*entity)() ) {
    consumer( entity() );
}


Or use std::declval<Entity>() to procure an rvalue.

"means the same thing as:" Except if the class is incomplete. Prefer requires (Consumer consumer, Entity&& entity) { consumer( std::move(entity) ); } to have the same semantics.
